# Transitions between pages with refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

Today I found this website: http://skainteractive.com/agencia/

When I change from one page to another, it's a simple url change, refresh the page.
But the thing is, they manage to create a good effect on the page we were viewing before goes to the new page.

I took a look at their source code, but I wasn't able to find out how they did that.
I know there is some ways to do that, but I would like to know how they did it. Cause it looks very well.

Here is another example of a good use of this effect:
http://www.casadacalcada.com/

How can they do that?

Comment: Check out jQuery Mobile for examples of page transitions - jQuery Mobile uses AJAX generally but it's a starting point

Comment: Why is this so downvoted?

Comment: @aquinas Because it shows no real effort.

Comment: SO is a site for specific coding questions. Try asking questions like this- "I'm trying to get X effect, I've tried methods Y and Z, but Its not producing the desired effect X. `Here's the code I've tried` Can anyone help me with this?"

Comment: [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)

Comment: @cimmanon. Hmm ok. Usually I'm pretty brutal about downvoting questions. In this case OP said they checked the source code and weren't able to figure it out. What else should they try before asking?

Comment: @aquinas Judging from their tags, they clearly understand that JavaScript/jQuery is involved (either that or they stuffed in every tag they could think of that would be relevant).  Did they try disabling JS to verify?  Did they try googling the names of the JS files used by those sites to see what they're used for?  Better yet, did they read the source of the JS files?  I don't mean to come off as a dick, but one of the sites has 15 JS files (I wish I were exaggerating).  SO isn't for reverse engineering someone else's site.

Answer (score 7):

They are not transitioning between pages. In fact, you are in the same page you landed.

What they are doing is:

- Loading HTML via AJAX requests. For the first site, the HTML is embedded in the JSON response, along with other data. Once the response is received, they extract the HTML from the response and put it on the current page.
- They're using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to appear as if they are moving the browser across pages by changing the page's url and modifying the browser's history to make the back and forward buttons work.

Comment: What's horrible about using JSON (AJAX?) to load pages?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard It would have been better to load blank HTML templates via AJAX, and JSON for the data, rather than use JSON to load escaped HTML. *Suboptimal* might be the right word.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Check the network tab of your dev tools and see what happens when transitioning through sections of the site.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't even click on those links.

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery for this, to show a new div:

`$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#more").click(function() {
            $("#show").fadeIn("slow");
        });
});`

where #more is the div(click) where it makes the div #show visible by a fade in. Be sure to set : `#show{
    display:none;
}`